# Angular 4/5 delete child element at particular index

Tags: angular

I have an input tag with type="number". When I increment number, it inserts/adds element inside div. Now I want to delete the last element on decrement. How do I do it?

HTML code :-

```
<input class="form-control" (click)="bedroomClick($event)" type="number" value="0" min="0">
<div class="row bedding-configuration" #bedding_config>
</div>
```

Angular code :-

```
previousBedRoomValue : number = 0;
bedroomClick(event) {

  if(event.target.value > this.previousBedRoomValue) {
    this.createBeddingConfigElements();
  }
  else {
    this.removeChildElement();
  }
  this.previousBedRoomValue = event.target.value;
}
```

createBeddingConfigElements() ==> Adds element inside div when input counter is incremented by 1. What I am looking for is to delete last element when counter is decremented by 1.

Comment: Pls share a code sample of you've tried or done so far.

Comment: I've shared html code sample. Here, when I click down arrow of input tag it should delete last element inside div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use (input) directive to catch that event and push or splice the array of divs to get the right number of divs. Example Code:

In component.html

```
<input type="number" value="0" min="0" (input)="addDiv()" [(ngModel)]="divsNumber">

<div *ngFor="let div of divs">div {{ div }}</div>
```

---

In component.ts

```
divs: Array<number> = [];

oldDivsNumber: number = 0;
divsNumber: number = 0;

addDiv = () => {
    if (this.divsNumber > this.oldDivsNumber) {
        this.divs.push(this.divs.length + 1);
    } else {
        this.divs.splice(this.divs.length - 1, 1);
    }
    this.oldDivsNumber = this.divsNumber;
}
```

You can check the live version [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xzivxv).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is showing [object HTMLDivElement] in browser.

Comment: In the above example div is text. In my case it is supposed to create element and insert it in DOM.

Comment: May I ask why do you want to insert it to the DOM? You can add html inside the div and also insert some dynamic data.

Comment: Sorry, it is not DOM it is HTML. I wanted to insert created element in HTML. I created html elements using renderer2 and I was also able to insert it in HTML. Problem was while deleting element. The example you showed has div as text and not tag. It would have helped me if you have showed it with say input tag like on increment it adds input tag inside div and remove it(using LIFO method) on decrement. I got the solution.

Comment: I have created a new example (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wdsdg4) with input created dynamically and you can get the value of that input text inside of divs array. I have converted a divs array to object that contains a number (divs number) and input (the text of input). I have also included a debug json print at the bottom, so you can see what is going on when you write something to the input.

Comment: Thanks @GregorOjstersek. I already posted the answer that is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use *ngIf to show when appropiate

```
<input class="form-control" (click)="bedroomClick($event)" type="number" 
 value="0" min="0">

<div class="row bedding-configuration" #bedding_config *ngIf="showBeddingConfig">
</div>
```

and in your code just set showBeddingConfig to true or false in bedroomClick()

Comment: The elements are dynamically created when user clicks on up arrow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did.

Code in component.ts =>

```
previousBedRoomValue : number = 0;

bedroomClick(event) {

  if(event.target.value > this.previousBedRoomValue ) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.addresidenceForm.controls['bedroom_config'];
    control.push(this.initBedroomConfiguration());
  }
  else {
    const control = <FormArray>this.addresidenceForm.controls['bedroom_config'];
    control.removeAt(event.target.value);
  }
  this.previousBedRoomValue = event.target.value;
}
```

Code in .html file.

```
<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 grid-margin">
  <div class="make-center mb-4 mt-4"></div>
  <input class="form-control" name="bedrooms" (click)="bedroomClick($event)" type="number" value="0" min="0">
  <label for="bedrooms">Bedrooms</label>
</div>
```

On click event it adds elements in html page.

```
<div [hidden]= "i == 0" *ngFor = "let bedRoom of addresidenceForm['controls'].bedroom_config['controls']; let i = index" class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 grid-margin" >
  <div [formGroupName]="i" class="loop-beddingSection">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 grid-margin">
        <label for="bedRoom"><sup class="orange-color">*</sup>Bedroom Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="bedroom_name" formControlName="bedroom_name">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is image.

[When number is 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLaGg.png)

[When number is 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW9h3.png)

[When number is 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bA5FM.png)